# App to choose layout according to situations

Tags: android

I am making a messaging android app, but my question is, how can I make the app choose either to pick the right hand layout or left hand layout? Like we see in messaging apps like WhatsApp, if I am the sender, my Message is wrapped in a right hand layout whilst the persons messages am chatting with are wrapped in a left handed layout, How can I achieve this type of Interface or layout I should say?

Below is my code, the app simple receives data from a remote database and puts it in a listview, using a custom adapter:

```
// the Data being set to the adapter
private ArrayList<ListItem> getListData() {
    ArrayList<ListItem> listMockData = new ArrayList<ListItem>();
    String[] username = mUsername.toArray(new String[mUsername.size()]);
    String[] comments = Comment.toArray(new String[Comment.size()]);

    for (int i = 0; i < username.length; i++) {

        ListItem newsData = new ListItem();

        newsData.setUsername(username[i]);
        newsData.setmComment(comments[i]);

        listMockData.add(newsData);
        System.gc();
    }
    return listMockData;
}
```

And my custom adapter utilizing a single view:

```
public class CommentAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
    private ArrayList<ListItem> listData;
    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
    ViewHolder holder;
    public CommentAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<ListItem> listData) {
        this.listData = listData;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
        layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return listData.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return listData.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.singlecomment, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.username = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.usernme);
            holder.message = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.postCommentBox);

            convertView.setTag(holder);

        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        ListItem newsItem = listData.get(position);
        holder.username.setText(newsItem.getUsername());
        holder.message.setText(newsItem.getmComment());

        return convertView;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        TextView username;
        TextView message;    
    }    
}
```

Comment: Can you show some code demonstrating what you've tried so far?

Comment: I have updated my question, my code is included now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your `ListItem` object has a field named `isSender` to check whether he is the sender or not.

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
  if (convertView == null) {
    convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.singlecomment, null);
    holder = new ViewHolder();
    holder.username = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.usernme);
    holder.message = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.postCommentBox);

    convertView.setTag(holder);

  } else {
    holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
  }

  ListItem newsItem = listData.get(position);
  if(newsItem.getIsSender()) {
    holder.usernameRight.setText(newsItem.getUsername());
    holder.messageRight.setText(newsItem.getmComment());
    holder.usernameLeft.setVisibility(View.GONE); // or something like that to hide
    holder.messageLeft.setText(View.GONE);
  } else {
    holder.usernameLeft.setText(newsItem.getUsername());
    holder.messageLeft.setText(newsItem.getmComment());
    holder.usernameRight.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    holder.messageRight.setText(View.GONE);
  }

  return convertView;
}
```